# onEnd in CountdownTimer with bool

Tags: list, flutter, dart, boolean

I tried to set a bool to true when my CountdownTimer() from the package flutter_countdown_timer: 1.5.0 is finished. But it changes all my CountdownTimer from my ListView. I think I must to use a List but I don't know how to use that. I am a beginner, be indulgent please. This is my code :

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_countdown_timer/flutter_countdown_timer.dart';
import './data.dart';
import './favorite_screen.dart';
import './home_list.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class Item {
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final String imageURL;
  final int countdown;
  final int id;
  final bool boole;

  Item({
    this.title,
    this.description,
    this.imageURL,
    this.countdown,
    this.id,
    this.boole,
  });
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List<Item> savedItems = new List<Item>();
  //List<bool> addFavorite = List<bool>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Home'),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                onPressed: () => pushToFavorite(context))
          ],
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: itemData.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              bool isSaved = savedItems.contains(itemData[index]);
              return Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        TextObject(
                            itemData[index].title, itemData[index].description),
                        TimerWidget(itemData[index].countdown),
                        Spacer(),
                        Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, top: 8.0),
                            child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                                    child: GestureDetector(
                                      child: Icon(
                                        isSaved
                                            ? Icons.favorite
                                            : Icons.favorite_border,
                                        color: isSaved ? Colors.red : null,
                                        size: 32,
                                      ),
                                      onTap: () {
                                        setState(() {
                                          if (isSaved) {
                                            savedItems.remove(itemData[index]);
                                            isSaved = false;
                                          } else {
                                            savedItems.add(itemData[index]);
                                            isSaved = true;
                                          }
                                        });
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ])),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              );
            }));
  }

  Future pushToFavorite(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => Favorite(favoriteItem: savedItems)));
  }
}
```

**timerWidget.dart**

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_countdown_timer/flutter_countdown_timer.dart';

class TextObject extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String description;
  const TextObject(this.title, this.description);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Spacer(),
        //Titre
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
          child: FittedBox(
            child: Text(
              title,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        //Decription
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 15.0),
          child: Text(
            description,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
          ),
        ),
        Spacer(),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class TimerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final int date;
  const TimerWidget(
    this.date,
  );

  @override
  _TimerWidgetState createState() => _TimerWidgetState();
}

class _TimerWidgetState extends State<TimerWidget> {
  bool finished = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
        child: finished == false ? CountdownTimer(
          daysSymbol: new Text("j "),
          hoursSymbol: new Text(" : "),
          minSymbol: new Text(" : "),
          secSymbol: new Text(""),
          endTime: widget.date,
          textStyle: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 14,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          onEnd: () {
            setState(() {
              finished = true;
            });
          },
        ) : Text('It is finished'));
  }
}
```

Thanks !